# Como obtener el texto de un select

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente código donde deseo seleccionar el value y text de un select, y esos valores enviarlos a unos inputs

```js
var $select = $("#id_maquinaria").change(function() {
            var x = $select.val();

            document.getElementById('area').value = x;

        });
```

```html
<select class="" name="" id="id_maquinaria">
  <option value="1">Maquina 1</option>
  <option value="2">Maquina 2</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="text" name="area" id="area" value="">
<br>
<input type="text" name="maquina" id="maquina" value="">
```

No logro poder seleccionar el text

Comment: O sea `Maquina 1` o `Maquina 2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

para seleccionar el texto del `option` seleccionado debes seleccionar dicho `option` y luego capturar su contenido con el método `.text()`.

En tu código solo tengo una observación y es que si estás usando **jQuery** lo uses lo mas que puedas, para que utilizar selectores de **JavaScript** nativo ?

Acá te dejo un ejemplo del código funcional:

```js
$("#id_maquinaria").change(function() {
  var valor = $(this).val(); // Capturamos el valor del select
  var texto = $(this).find('option:selected').text(); // Capturamos el texto del option seleccionado

  $("#area").val(valor);
  $("#maquina").val(texto);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="" name="" id="id_maquinaria">
  <option value="">Seleccionar máquina</option>
  <option value="1">Maquina 1</option>
  <option value="2">Maquina 2</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="text" name="area" id="area" value="">
<br>
<input type="text" name="maquina" id="maquina" value="">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Podrías obtenerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
var $select = $("#id_maquinaria").change(function() {
  // obtengo el value
  var value = $(this).val();
  // obtengo el texto segun el value
  var text = $select.find('option[value=' + value + ']').text();
  
  // imprime el seleccionado
  console.log(value, text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="" name="" id="id_maquinaria">
  <option value="1">Maquina 1</option>
  <option value="2">Maquina 2</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="text" name="area" id="area" value="">
<br>
<input type="text" name="maquina" id="maquina" value="">
```

Comment: Al fin logre hacerlo con tu ejemplo, funciona a la perfección!

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el "innerHtml" del option seleccionado hay muchas maneras, espero darte una guía con el siguiente código.

```
select = document.getElementById("id_maquinaria");
select.onchange = function(){ // Podemos crear una función que reaccione cuando cambia el valor del select como prueba.
    console.log(this.value); //regresa el value del option seleccionado
    console.log(this.innerHTML); //regresa el select completo con todas sus opciones
    //Si no lo quieres usar dentro de una función podrías usar la variable que ya creamos de 'select' en lugar de 'this'
    var options = this.getElementsByTagName("option"); //Te regresa un arrego con todos los options de tu select
    var optionHTML = options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML;  //Te regresa el innetHTML (Maquina 1 o Maquina 2) del option seleccionado
    console.log(optionHTML); //Aquí te queda para quelo uses como gustes!
};
```

En resumen, obtenemos el elemento select a través de su ID, luego sacamos las options a modo de arreglo con el 'getElementsByTagName' y del arreglo seleccionamos el que tiene como índice el que fue seleccionado a través del atributo "selectedIndex"

Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, esta solo es una que creo que es simple para lo que necesitas implementar.